# Receive users Hostname in Php Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php

I have this script to handle the contact form on my website in php and I want it to send me the users hostname so I can quickly see local hostnames and spend more time on those emails. Here is the javascript from the contact page

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data)
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
            {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if(label)
                {
                    $btn.prop('type','submit' );
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                }
            });

        }//else
    }

    $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            $btn.prop('type','button' );
            $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });


                    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'handler.php',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: after_form_submitted,
                dataType: 'json'
            });

      });
});
</script>
```

and here is the php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);




$pp->sendEmailTo('michaex4@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

How do I make this work? I have no experience in PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by users hostname ?  have a look at **$_SERVER** variable in your debugger when the form is submitted.  What information do you want from there ?

Comment: For example. d198-53-201-183.abhsia.telus.net.   this is a hostname from a Canadian internet service providers ip address.

Comment: No, at the best you can get their ip address.

Comment: Be careful with this idea. You won't always get a hostname for a given machine. Sometimes you can't even get an IP address. Even if you do, the hostname and IP address don't always reflect the users location. For example, working from the details you might get from my home network connection, you'd think I was several hundred miles away. There was a period when I couldn't order pizza from a local outlet because their phone system though my Internet phone connection was at the other end of the country and insisted on connecting me to one of their outlets there.

Comment: If you care about locality, ask the users to submit their postcode/zip code, or nearest city, or even just the country name or something, depending on the level of detail you need. You can't get the host name, and IP address is a very unreliable indicator of physical location (as would be the hostname too, even if you could get it). Also, people might submit data while they're travelling just because it's convenient, when really their home location is somewhere else. I don't think you've entirely thought this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can their hostname.  However you can get their ipaddress most of the time.  Here is my function to do that.  I use it send it to me by email from my contact form.

```php
function User_IP ()
{if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}
 elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];}
 else
    {$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}
 return $ip;
}
```

Before sending the email, something like this should work

```php
$validator->field('message') = 'Users IP : '.User_IP ().
  '<br>\r\n'.$validator->field('message')
```

I have expanded it out for clarity.  The 
 does a newline if its an html email and the **\r\n** for text. For an html email, there is no harm in using both.

Comment: Can you show me how to add this to the above code please? I don't understand php.

Comment: could you edit your code so it all is contained in one file please? I don't know how to use php.

Comment: @user3000742 stackoverflow isn't a free outsourcing service. It's a site for programmers to help other programmers. You're expected to know at least some basics about the code you're working with. If you need someone to create you a complete solution and do everything for you, you need to hire a freelancer

Comment: Its just a simple script. Im not asking people to spend hours working for free for me. This thing should only take a minute or two.

Comment: For one, you are using an addon that I haven't used.  Even if I were to give you the whole script, it would not work, because I don't know what library you have used (and I have no experience in it).  Also, as indicated by @ADyson, you are expected to know some programming.  It is a trivial task to insert my code fragments into your script.  If you are not able to do that, then it indicates that you are either terrified of coding, or have no knowledge of coding in any language.  Please make an effort.

Comment: And, you will need to make changes, it`s the nature of software.

Comment: Ok I see your point. I thought this was a simple fix. It uses phpmailer btw.